# Run sgml-pretty-print when opening an xml file in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I can currently use sgml-pretty-print to pretty print an xml file in emacs, but it's a manual process:

1. M-<
2. C-space
3. M->
4. M-x sgml-pretty-print

I'd like this to happen automatically (or at least have some option to do so).  I'm new to emacs/elisp, and do not understand how:

1. emacs knows what code to run when you open a file (does this start in files.el?)
2. If you wanted to override that code with your own, how to do that

Comment: You can close up the 1st and 3rd steps by typing `C-h` which selects the whole buffer.

Comment: for YOU it does, but for me C-h is the first key in a sequence, to get help on various topics.

Comment: Sorry, mistyped it, I meant `C-x h`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'my-sgml-find-file-hook)
(defun my-sgml-find-file-hook ()
  "run sgml pretty-print on the file when it's opened (if it's sgml)"
  (when (eq major-mode 'sgml-mode)
    (sgml-pretty-print (point-min) (point-max))))
```

The key pieces of information are the [find-file-hook](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Visiting-Functions.html#Visiting-Functions), [point-min](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Point.html) (-max), and [major-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Major-Modes.html#Major-Modes).

If you want to learn more about elisp, you can take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522/tips-for-learning-elisp), which gives some pointers on how to figure things out.

Comment: Furthermore, you can wrap the `sgml-pretty-print` function call in a `y-or-n-p` conditional statement to ask whether one wants the content to be pretty printed or not.

Answer (score 4):

A slightly simpler alternative to [Trey Jackson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889649/run-sgml-pretty-print-when-opening-an-xml-file-in-emacs/889691#889691).  Just add this to your `~/.emacs` file:

```
(add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook #'(lambda ()
  (sgml-pretty-print (point-min) (point-max))))
```

Comment: Yes, it's a bit simpler, but TJ's solution allows you to run the function manually, too.